# view current user documents in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i try to show documents with specific department id

computer-science admin will be able to view only computer-science documents and hr admin view only hr documents

here i create a sp

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sphrdocid1]

     @DepID int
   as
    SELECT DocumentInfo.DocID,
 dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName,
    dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile,
   dbo.DocType.DocType,
   dbo.Department.DepType ,
    dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType AS ApproveID
    FROM dbo.DocumentInfo
       left JOIN dbo.DocType ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID=dbo.DocType.DocTypeID
 left JOIN dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID=dbo.Department.DepID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ApproveType ON  
    dbo.ApproveType.approveid=dbo.Department.DepID            
     where    
 dbo.Department.DepID=@DepID
```

then when i test the query and write this "sphrdocid1 6" it show me like this

```
 DocID DocDesciption    DocName     Uploadfile       DocTypeID     
    **DepID**                 **UploadedBy**                 UserID

8   paperssSSS  SDASDASD        dsfsdf.docx 1
**4**                      **john**                 **6**

9   hr report   dr reprt n analysis     HR.docx 1
**4**                                   **john**             **6**
```

and on page load function

```
 GrdFileApprove.DataSource = dd.hrdoc1(Convert.ToInt32(Session["a"]));
          GrdFileApprove.DataBind();
```

and

```
 public DataTable hrdoc1(int id)
    {
        return db.ExecuteDataSet("sphrdocid1", new object[] { id }).Tables[0];


    }
```

when i set a breakpoint it shows me id 0 ..

and  when i debug it can not show me any documents in form

where is the probelem?

Comment: Have you used SQL profiler before? You can use it to see if your query is even executed.

Comment: i update store procedure .. check it..@StingyJack

Comment: i think the problem is at ASP .net site as you said `Convert.ToInt32(Session["Userid"])`  gives you 0 so please be sure that you store data when any user logs in your system

Comment: i already store data in database when any user logs

Comment: In SQL Profiler, do you see your query being executed? Can you execute the text that is captured from SQL profiler and get a result?

Comment: yes query is successfully executed